# import files inside packages - Project Structure

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have some doubts in relation to packages structure in a python project when I make the imports

These are some conventions

**`python-irodsclient_API = Project Name`**

I've defined python packages for each file, in this case are the following:

**`python-irodsclient_API/config/`**

**`python-irodsclient_API/connection/`**

*These packages are well define as a packages and not as a directories really?*

[image]

I have the file **`python-irodsclient_API/config/config.py`** in which I've defined some constants about of configuration for connect with my server:

[image]

And I have the **`python-irodsclient_API/connection/connection.py`** file:

[image]

In the last or previous image (highlighted in red) .. is this the right way of import the files?

I feel the sensation of this way is not better.
I know that the "imports" should be relatives and not absolutes (for the path) and that is necessary use "." instead "*"
In my case I don't know if this can be applied in relation to the I'm doing in the graphics.

I appreciate your help and orientation
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial about this in the [Python module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), which explains how to refer to packages under structured folders.

Basically, `from x import y`, where `y` is a submodule name, allows you to use `y.z` instead of `x.y.z`.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1) make your project a package. Since it seems like your `connection` and `config` packages are interdependent, they should be modules within the same package. To make this happens, add a `__init__.py` files in `python-irodsclient_API` folder. Now you can use relative imports to import `config` into `connection`, as they are part of the same package:

```
from ..config import config
```

The `..` part means import from one level above within the package structure (similar to how `..` means parent directory in Unix)

2) if you don't want to make `python-irodsclient_API` a package for some reason, then the second option is to add that folder to the PYTHONPATH. You can do this dynamically per Tony Yang's answer, or do this from the bash command line as followed:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/python-irodsclient_API
```

Answer (score 0):

I can invoke sys module to append python-irodsclient_API path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\..\python-irodsclient_API')
```

When you operate connection.py and want to invoke config, it's able to be successful.